# Get a term each custom post type

Tags: posts, customization

I have a problem to get the term of custom posts list.
I have 2 taxonomies on my custom post type. one of them is "visa_processing". and I am trying to create a list (table, tr, td)
"Name1, Name2, passport num, processing."

"processing" is a term and each different.

I need to get "processing" term on list for each posts.

ex) 
John, Smith, K009923, waiting
Price, Mark, K009923, failed
Jordan, MC, K009923, issued

"applied, waiting, failed, issued"  <--- these are terms of the taxonomy "visa_processing".

But terms are not showing or printed "Array". how can I fix it?

```
 $args = array(
'post_type'   => $post_type,
'numberposts' => $limit,
'post_status' => $status,
);
$posts = get_posts( $args );
if( count($posts) ):
$return .= '<table>';
foreach( $posts as $post ): setup_postdata( $post );

/** get meta values and replace **/
$getPassport = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_Passport', true );
$getPassport_replaced = substr_replace($getPassport, "*", 3).'*****';

$getName1 = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_Name1', true );
$getName2 = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_Name2', true );
$getName2_replaced = substr_replace($getName2, "*", 3).'***';
//$getNames = get_the_title();  // 전체 이름 : 사용안함

//$processing = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'visa_processing', array("orderby"=>"term_order"));
//$processing = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'visa_processing');
//$processing = wp_get_object_terms( get_the_ID(), 'visa_processing' );
//echo get_the_ID();

//$terms = get_the_terms();   print_r($terms);


  $return .= '<tr><td>' . $getName1 .'&nbsp;'. $getName2_replaced .'</td>  <td>'.$getPassport_replaced.'</td><td>'.$processing.'</td></tr>';

 endforeach; wp_reset_postdata();
   $return .= '</table></div>'; //#recent_visas
 else :
   $return .= '<p>No posts found.</p>';
 endif;
```

return $return;

Answer (score 1):

or printed "Array"

That is your clue. Array indicates something is being returned, you just need to make use of it.

Try var_dump($processing) and see what the array contains. In my plugins I have a functioned called example_var_dump(); and it is setup to use

```
 before the var_dump() line and
```

after it. This displays arrays in a readable fashion.

Plus I have a global variable for debugging mode. If that is set to false, my example_var_dump() function does nothing. This is to avoid dumping information in a released version after forgetting to removing var_dump() in complex scripts. Just a tip.

Comment: array(1) { [15]=> object(stdClass)#494 (10) { ["term_id"]=> string(2) "15" ["name"]=> string(6) "waiting" ["slug"]=> string(18) "abceodkd" ["term_group"]=> string(1) "0" ["term_taxonomy_id"]=> string(2) "15" ["taxonomy"]=> string(15) "visa_processing" ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["parent"]=> string(1) "0" ["count"]=> string(1) "2" ["object_id"]=> string(3) "488" } } 


I got like this from var_dump($processing). I found "waiting" on name. so I tried echo $processing["name"]; but it says "bool(false)". I am sorry for my poor php. how can I fix it?

Comment: opps. it's not saying "bool(false)". it comes null.

Comment: Hey, we all start somewhere. That object is "stdClass". Try this... echo $processing->name;   your going to make excellent progress in future once you learn these basics ;)